# How to track movements in a room with Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-gps

The need is to track the user moving in small areas (for example at home, in a garden, in a museum, or in some rooms) with Android Studio (Java) drawing the path he does on the screen.

I can use `StepCouter` to count the user steps and the distance walked. But what about the path? I thought of using the GPS location but his best accuracy (`PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`) is between 10 and 100 meters, non enough for a house (unless you have a huge villa).

So how to track (and draw) the path in small areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of solutions:

1. Using [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview) (BLE) beacons to track indoor positioning.
2. Using an external GPS (outdoors) using mock location in developer mode on Android. Instructions on how to do that can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gXPUeyUSVw).

Use these permissions in the Android Manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

You'll need to activate mock location in the developer settings on the Android device and then connect the external GPS via bluetooth.